# Type password automatically for RDP connection (CredentialUIBroker)

Tags: c#, testing, rdp, flaui

As an exercise, I'm trying to automate typing RDP credentials using FlaUI.
My OS is Windows 10.

I'm able to start mstsc.exe and type into this window:

[image: mstsc window]

But then I get this window and I can't find it anywhere:

[image: Credential Manager UI Host window]

It's not an mstsc window, even though it appears above it as a modal window: mstsc always has just one window.
Apparently it's a window of "Credential Manager UI Host", but that process has... zero windows.

Even in task manager it's listed in the background tasks and not in the applications section.
FlaUI Inspect doesn't see it at all.

By the way, this is my code:

```
var CurrentAutomation = new UIA3Automation();
var Process = Application.Attach(Process.GetProcessesByName("CredentialUIBroker")[0]);
var Windows = Process.GetAllTopLevelWindows(CurrentAutomation); // 0 elements
```

How can I get a handle to this window and access its textbox using FlaUI?

Comment: You can not (not easily). That windows is protected at the operative system level to isolate it. You would need to develop a input driver, so it is a trusted input (simulate a keyboard) to make it work.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? RDP is what it says - a way to create a remote desktop. Not a remote automation technology. There are *a ton* of remote access and automation technologies, starting from remote registry access and going all the way to [Powershell Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7)

Comment: You don't need UI automation to work with Remote Desktop either. You can pass command line parameters [to the mstsc command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mstsc) to specify the target server and possibly [a connection file with settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/rdp-files).

Comment: You can also enable [single-sign on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc742808(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to connect using the current user account

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos, those are all good ideas. The thing is that the remote server doesn't allow logins using saved credentials. I'm aware of other [applications](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-remote-desktop/9wzdncrfj3ps?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) that can somehow bypass this, but I like automation and consider it both an excercise and a dare, using FlaUI. Also, I have to use credentials that differ from those of my current user account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out it was just a matter of knowing the name of the "window", which is Credential Dialog Xaml Host; also, it can be found using FlaUI Inspect.

Once the mstsc part is done and the "Windows Security" window comes out, you can go on with this sample code:

```
// Declare all variables, which might be method parameters instead
var Password = "MyLamePassword";
var MaxTimeout = new TimeSpan(10 * 1000 * 2000);
var CurrentAutomation = new UIA3Automation();
var Desktop = CurrentAutomation.GetDesktop();

// Get the window, using a Retry call to wait for it to be available
var CredentialWindow = Retry
    .WhileEmpty(
        () => Desktop.FindAllDescendants(f => f.ByClassName("Credential Dialog Xaml Host")),
        timeout: MaxTimeout,
        throwOnTimeout: true)
    .Result[0];

// Get the password box
AutomationElement PasswordBox = null;
Retry.WhileNull(
    () => PasswordBox = CredentialWindow.FindFirstDescendant(f => f.ByName("Password").And(f.ByControlType(ControlType.Edit))),
    timeout: MaxTimeout,
    throwOnTimeout: true);

// Type the password
PasswordBox.FocusNative();
Keyboard.Type(Password);

// I have some Retry code here too, just to check that the password is actually typed, and type Enter after it. 

CurrentAutomation.Dispose();
```